# Ajax contact form returnig 0

Tags: ajax, forms, json

I have read through a lot of responses on this site and am unable to find the issue with my code.

The form is :

```
<?php while (have_posts()) : the_post()?>
        <form  method='post'  id="dav-international" >
            <label for="dav-address">Address:</label><input type="text" name="dav-address" id="dav-address"/>
            <button type="submit" id="submit">Submit</button>
            </form>
<?php endwhile;?>
```

The functions are in `function.php` ( home-page is already enqueued ):

```
    add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'dav_script');
    function dav_script(){
        if (is_front_page()){
            $dav_nonce = wp_create_nonce('contact_form');
            wp_localize_script('home-page', 'ajaxObj', array(
                    'ajaxurl' => admin_url('admin-ajax.php'),
                    'nonce' => $dav_nonce,
            ));
        }
    }




    add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_dav_validation', 'dav_form_validation');
    add_action('wp_ajax_dav_validation', 'dav_form_validation');


function dav_form_validation(){
    global $wpdb;
    if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == 'POST'){
    check_ajax_referer('contact_form');
    $dav_address = sanitize_text_field($_POST['info']);

    $dav_ajax_data = array();
        $dav_ajax_data['dav-address'] = $dav_address;

    echo json_encode($dav_ajax_data);
    }
    wp_die();
}
```

and the jQuery is :

```
var $j = jQuery;
                    $j('#submit').click(function(e){
                        var $j = jQuery;
                        e.preventDefault();
                        if ($j('#dav-address').val().length > 0){
                            var formInfo = $j('form').serialize();
                            var formdata = {
                                action : 'dav_validation',
                                  _ajax_nonce: ajaxObj.nonce,
                                  info : formInfo
                            }
                            $j.ajax({
                                type:'post',
                                url: ajaxObj.ajaxurl,
                                data: formdata,
                                success: function(data){
                                    console.log(data);
                                }
                            })
                        }
                        });
```

I believe I followed the instructions on WordPress codex properly but the console continues to output 0. I am stuck on this and cannot seem to figure it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved the problem thanks to the guidance of @shanebp: 
The issue was how the data was being called through PHP and ajax. Instead of using the name attribute in the input field, I used var_dump to see what $_POST was outputting and found that the array created (formdata) in jQuery was what $_POST was retrieving. Instead of using the name attribute, I had to return the info key passed through the formdata array in my ajax. I am guessing this is how wordpress uses ajax and php.

Answer (score 0):

What makes you think this will ever be true?

```
if (isset($_POST['submit'])){
```

In `function dav_form_validation` the `die()` is in 2 conditionals.  It should be called regardless of whether the conditionals are satisfied. Add 2 else clauses and return error messages.

Usually a response of '0', means the ajax hooks are not being found. But your code *seems* okay in that regard.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the response. I added the isset ($_POST['submit']) because I was trying things I saw in other posts. When I took it out and moved the die() to the end of the function I am getting an empty array. Would you know why this would occur? Thanks

Comment: Remove this: if (isset($dav_address)){

Comment: I did and the console is returning:

Comment: <b>Notice</b>:  Undefined index: dav-address in <b>C:\xampp\htdocs\wordpress\wp-content\themes\Chevalier Transport copy\functions.php</b> on line <b>112</b><br />
{"dav-address":""}

Comment: I solved it, thanks a lot. I thought something was wrong with my code, but it was the way PHP and ajax worked.